# Generating comments for a data structure that *wasn't* loaded via RoundTripLoader?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a data structure that I would like to add comments to, then convert into YAML.

I'd like to avoid outputting the data structure as YAML and loading it back in using `RoundTripLoader`.

Is there a way to convert my data structure into one that supports the ruamel.yaml comments interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, although the interface for that is not guaranteed to be stable.
Because of that, and the lack of documentation, it often helps to look at the representation of `round_trip_loading()` your expected output, or a small sample thereof.

You'll have to realise that comments are attached to, special versions of, the representation of the structured nodes (mapping and sequence). For a mapping that would `safe_load()` as a Python `dict`, this is a `CommentedMap()` and for a sequence, that would load as a Python `list`, this is a `CommentedSeq()`.

Both these classes can have a `.ca` attribute holding the comments that may occur before the structural node, as end-of-line-comments after a key/value pair resp. item, on its own line between key-value pairs or items, and at the end of a node.

That means you have to convert any `dict` or `list` you have, that needs commenting on (which can be done automatically/recursively e.g. by the routine `comment_prep()`), and then find the correct point and way to attach the comment. *Because the comment manipulation routines have not stabilized,  make sure you wrap your comment adding routines to get a single place where to update in case they do change.*

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import round_trip_dump as rtd
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq

# please note that because of the dict the order of the keys is undetermined
data = dict(a=1, b=2, c=['x', 'y', dict(k='i', l=42, m='∞')])

rtd(data, sys.stdout)
print('-' * 30)


def comment_prep(base):
    """replace all dict with CommentedMap and list with CommentedSeq"""
    if isinstance(base, dict):
        ret_val = CommentedMap()
        for key in sorted(base):  # here we force sorted order
            ret_val[key] = comment_prep(base[key])
        return ret_val
    if isinstance(base, list):
        ret_val = CommentedSeq()
        for item in base:
            ret_val.append(comment_prep(item))
        return ret_val
    return base

data = comment_prep(data)
data['c'][2].yaml_add_eol_comment('# this is the answer', key='l', column=15)
rtd(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
c:
- x
- y
- k: i
  m: ∞
  l: 42
b: 2
a: 1
------------------------------
a: 1
b: 2
c:
- x
- y
- k: i
  l: 42        # this is the answer
  m: ∞
```

The file [test_comment_manipulation.py](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/6562185e565f21b37b0c1874e26ec8c734adb363/_test/test_comment_manipulation.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), has some more examples and is a good place to keep an eye on (as the interface changes, so will the tests in that file).

Comment: You can of course directly create the `CommentedSeq/Dict` instead of first making `list/dict`: `data = CommentedMap([
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', CommentedSeq(['x', 'y', CommentedMap([('k', 'i'), ('l', 42), ('m', '∞')])]))
])`. The list of tuples is necessary to keep the ordering in older versions of Python

Comment: Funnily enough I had most of that implementation already built. Should be very easy to add into my existing filtering system.

Comment: Next time you are stuck, include in your question what code you have, then it is easier to answer with exactly (and only) what you need.